# How to pass an API token as output variable between jobs in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm new to GitHub Actions (and yaml syntax) so I may be misunderstanding something about the ability to pass data between jobs: I've been trying to use a workflow with two jobs:

1. **authenticateWithAuth0API** asks for a token to be generated
2. **triggerNetlifyFunction** uses the token to authenticate with a Lambda function

For the first job, I can see that I do get back some kind of response that is saved as an output. The logs show the response is an access token with value ***. I assume the value appears as asterisks in the logs because the runner understands this value to be sensitive (a secret - though not a GitHub Secret).

I was under the impression that I could declare this as an output (which seems to go through ok) and then use it in the next job with the *"needs"* context. I'm using it as the value to the "Authorization" header for a call triggered in the next job.

However, in the logs I can see that the value of the header is empty showing up as **Authorization:""**. Am I missing something in terms of the ability to pass sensitive variables between jobs?

```
jobs:
  authenticateWithAuth0API:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs: 
      token: ${{ steps.getToken.outputs.API_RESPONSE }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - id: getToken
        uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@v1.8.0
        with:
          url: <<removed: some token generation endpoint>>
          data: '{"client_id":"${{ secrets.... }}","client_secret":"${{ secrets....}}","audience":"${{ secrets.... }}","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
      - id: saveResponse
        run: echo "::set-output name=API_RESPONSE"

  triggerNetlifyFunction:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: authenticateWithAuth0API
    steps:
      - id: callFunction
        uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@v1.8.0
        with:
          url: <<removed: netlify function url>>
          customHeaders: '{"Authorization":"${{ needs.authenticateWithAuth0API.outputs.token }}"}'
      - id: ShowFunctionResponse
        run: echo ${{ steps.callFunction.outputs.response }}
```

DEBUG LOGS FROM JOB1:

```
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'token'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
```

DEBUG LOGS FROM JOB2:

```
##[debug]Evaluating: format('{{"Authorization":"{0}"}}', needs.authenticateWithAuth0API.outputs.token)
##[debug]Evaluating format:
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> '{{"Authorization":"{0}"}}'
##[debug]..Evaluating Index:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating Index:
##[debug]........Evaluating needs:
##[debug]........=> Object
##[debug]........Evaluating String:
##[debug]........=> 'authenticateWithAuth0API'
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'outputs'
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'token'
##[debug]..=> null

...
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'token'
##[debug]..=> null
##[debug]=> '{"Authorization":""}'
##[debug]Result: '{"Authorization":""}'
##[debug]Loading env
```

Comment: If this is your current workflow, it seems to have a missing `steps` keyword on the `authenticateWithAuth0API` job which could be related.

Comment: Good catch thanks, but yes I do have a steps keyword in my actual file, I just copied the lines manually. Just updated. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Added debug logs... if i'm reading this correctly it seems that my output variable token is not a string, it's an object {access_token: *** }? But even so, why would it come up as "" (empty string in the authorization header)? Should it not have added an object at least?

Comment: I guess this is an expected behaviour as Github Actions runner couldn't check the output value and guarantee the secrets isn't exposed through the workflow. A workaround could be to save the output (API_RESPONSE) as a secret on the first job and access it as any other secret on the second job. [This action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gh-secrets) could help you do it (it would even update the secret if it is already set).

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd, reading around it seems that because of the nature of the variable, it won't let me use it in the context of another job..I'm surprised the runner can tell this is a secret(?!) assuming that this would work with any other variable. From the looks of it, there is no native way to set a GH Secret directly from the job either (maybe I'm wrong?). So, indeed this seems like the way to go but, I need to check if I can use such a marketplace action from a security standpoint. Feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok. For what I know, there is no native way to set a GH Secret directly from the job. But let me know if I'm wrong or if it will be implemented in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Added debug logs... if i'm reading this correctly it seems that my output variable token is not a string, it's an object `{access_token: *** }`? But even so, why would it come up as `""` (empty string in the authorization header)? Should it not have added an object at least?

I believe this is an expected behaviour as Github Actions runner probably can't check the output value, and ensure the secret isn't exposed through the workflow afterwards.

A workaround to your issue could be to save the output (*API_RESPONSE*) as a secret on the first job, and then access it as any other secret on the second job.

[This GH secrets action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gh-secrets) could help you do it (it would even update the secret if it is already set).

*Note: There may be other actions available providing a similar result.*